# What do "days represented" mean

Tags: support, reputation

Under [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/reputation) link, 4th line from the bottom, I found an item called "days represented". Could someone let me know what it means?

I was trying to find it in the help without any luck.

Comment: @TildalWave I get 42. When I count all the days I had a reputation change in my profile, it is 40, so your guess might be correct... probably with some caveat.